# Is there any way to use moderncv inside another document class?

Tags: document-classes, moderncv, books

In my thesis I need to have a cv. It would be awesome, if I could use moderncv. The only way I so far know is, to make seperate PDF, and include this afterwards within my thesis. Do you know any direct way to use moderncv e.g. in scrbook?

Comment: You cannot use two different document class in one document. The only solution is wath you already done I think.

Comment: Not the *only* solution. You could also see what's inside `moderncv`, understand it (not really necessary, but you will need at least to have an idea), and then copy the necessary code into a package you can use.

Comment: @doncherry, yes you are right. Sorry did not found it previously

Comment: @math No problem, it takes a bit of practice to find the right questions efficiently .. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already said in comment question put here for more visibility and show the question answer:

You cannot use two different document class in one document. The only solution is what you already done.