# koma-moderncvclassic in thesis

Tags: koma-script, moderncv, scrbook, cv

The `koma-moderncvclassic` package would in principle be the specific solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173179/is-there-any-way-to-use-moderncv-inside-another-document-class) (having a CV based on class `moderncv` in your thesis without including a PDF).

However, importing the package changes the document settings and thus interferes with the whole document.

Is there a nice way to have the settings only changed locally for the CV chapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess you do not want to hear this, but the answer is: **No, it is not possible.**

The reason for this is, that you are for example using command `\section` in your thesis, but package `koma-moderncvclassic` also wants to use it and redefined it to get the colored line in front of the section header.

So you can only have the `\section` defined in your thesis or in the package, but not both together.

There are only two possibilitys for you I can see:

1. Use package `pdfpages` (see documentation with `texdoc pdfpages` in your terminal/console) to include the cv into your thesis or
2. Copy package `koma-moderncvclassic.sty` to `mykoma-moderncvclassic.sty` and rework all used commands in it conflicting with commands with the same name in your thesis like `\section` to `\mysection` etc. Do not forget that the cv also uses a command `\maketitle`. If you want to use a bibliography in your cv you have the next problem using two bibliographys in your combined document. Last not least package `koma-moderncvclassic.sty` does not rebuild all possibilities you have in class `moderncv`. Depending on your current cv you have to recreate the missing commands for package `mykoma-moderncvclassic.sty`. 
   *To be honest it is not worth the work you will have with this!*

**Conclusion:**

The only real way to add an cv build with `moderncv` class into your thesis is to use point 1 (`pdfpages`).